# Parsing an ADS-B json file

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse ADS-B data to extract the values of specific elements that I want. I have posted a small portion of the json file below as an example. I have the code in python to read in the file but I am not sure how to extract specific components. For example I am interested in all of the values for "Id" "Lat" and "Long". How do I go about extracting those values?

Python Code:

```
import json

with open('Short_ADSB.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print(d)
```

Short_ADSB.json:

```
{"src":1,"feeds":[{"id":1,"name":"ADSBexchange.com","polarPlot":false}],"srcFeed":1,"showSil":true,"showFlg":true,"showPic":true,"flgH":20,"flgW":85,"acList":[{"Id":8721588,"Rcvr":1,"HasSig":false,"Icao":"8514B4","Bad":false,"Reg":"JA321J","FSeen":"\/Date(1466380828682)\/","TSecs":1,"CMsgs":1,"Alt":31000,"GAlt":31000,"AltT":0,"Tisb":false,"TrkH":false,"Type":"B738","Mdl":"Boeing 737NG 846/W","Man":"Boeing","CNum":"35350","Op":"Japan Airlines","OpIcao":"JAL","Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":2,"Species":1,"Engines":"2","EngType":3,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"Japan","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"Gnd":false,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"TT":"a","Trt":1,"Year":"2009"},{"Id":2961715,"Rcvr":1,"HasSig":false,"Icao":"2D3133","Bad":false,"FSeen":"\/Date(1466380828682)\/","TSecs":1,"CMsgs":1,"InHg":29.9409447,"AltT":0,"Lat":0.0,"Long":-2147.483648,"PosTime":1466380828682,"Mlat":false,"Tisb":false,"Spd":11308.0,"TrkH":false,"Sqk":"","VsiT":0,"WTC":0,"Species":0,"EngType":0,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"Unknown or unassigned country","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"ResetTrail":true,"TT":"a","Trt":2,"Cos":[0.0,-2147.483648,1466380828682.0,null]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to get the attributes present on JSON. Hope you can use this as a sample to get the required attribute.

```
import json

with open('Short_ADSB.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print(d)
    print(d["src"])
    print(d["feeds"])
    ## read from feeds array
    print(d["feeds"][0]["id"])
    print(d["acList"])
    print(d["acList"][0]["Id"])
print(d["acList"][1]["Lat"])
print(d["acList"][1]["Long"])
```

Comment: This is excellent! How would I iterate over the entire json file to extract all Lat and Long values? I know I want, for i in range(length(___)), but I am not sure what to fill in the blank. Thanks for the help!